# Removing "footer" from Classicthesis cover page

Tags: header-footer, classicthesis

I'm using the newest version (4.2) of the Classisthesis template to write my thesis. Included in the template is a footer-like piece of text that gets printed at the bottom of all pages - included the cover page.

While I like the idea of having eg. my thesis title on each page of my thesis, how can I remove it from the cover page... ?

I've traced the source of the piece of text to the following code snippet in classicthesis.sty:

```
% ********************************************************************
% Drafting Stuff
% ********************************************************************
\RequirePackage{scrtime} % time access
\newcommand{\finalVersionString}{\relax}
\providecommand{\myVersion}{$\!\!$} % w/o classicthesis-config.tex
\ifthenelse{\boolean{@drafting}}{%      
%    \RequirePackage{draftwatermark}%
%       \SetWatermarkLightness{0.9}
%           \SetWatermarkScale{.5}
%           \SetWatermarkText{\today\ at \thistime}
        \PassOptionsToPackage{draft}{prelim2e}
        \RequirePackage{prelim2e}
        \renewcommand{\PrelimWords}{\relax}
        \renewcommand{\PrelimText}{\footnotesize FOOTER TEXT, TYPICALLY THESIS TITLE}
}{\renewcommand{\finalVersionString}{\emph{Final Version} as of \today\ (\texttt{classicthesis}~\myVersion).}}
```

Comment: \thispagestyle{empty} should work.  Needless to say, without a complete MWE I didn't actually test this.

Comment: Remove the option `drafting` in `classicthesis-config` as is commented in the file.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the option `drafting` in `classicthesis-config` as is commented in the very same file.